# Component controller not updating in $onChanges

Tags: angularjs

I'm creating an Angular 1.5 component, and I'm stuck on something. I'm watching for changes to a bound input via `$onChanges`. When I console the data at the bottom of the function on `$onChanges`, all looks good, but it doesn't change in my view.

```
ctrl.$onChanges = function (changesObj) {
    if (/* test to see if new data is invalid */) {
        ctrl.test = 2;
        console.log(2);
        // return;
    } else {
        var newData = changesObj.data.currentValue;
        ctrl.test = 1;
        console.log(1);
    }
};
```

I've console logged test in the if statement, and I get a bunch of logs. The first is true, as expected, but the rest come up false. The logs of above are simply:

```
    2
(8) 1
```

However, when I display `test` in my view, it's always 2. I even console logged the state of `ctrl.test` at the bottom of the function, and it's fine there, but the view stays 2.

Is there something I need to do in Angular 1.5 components to trigger the update from the controller to the view? It seems to work once, but only once?

Comment: may be you can wrap your if statement within $apply, so that the digest cycle is called and it will reflect immediately in the view.

Comment: Except the 1.5 components don't natively have a scope, and we're encouraged to not use $scope, aren't we? There is no $apply on the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Hope it helps

```
function updateValue(data){

}

function componentController() {
    function setType() {
       // you will get changes on this object
       // do your stuff here
       console.log(this)
       updateValue.apply(this,[this.data])
    }
    this.$onInit = setType;
    this.$onChanges = setType;
}
```

Comment: Adding it to init did't do anything. I had already initialized the values before. The problem is they're not updating.

Comment: @RhoVisions - you can use apply()

Comment: I'm confused on what `updateValue` is? How does a random function have an apply method?